# Multiple inner joins get_posts WooCommerce / WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

I am running WooCommerce with Storefront theme and my category pages are quite slow. When I monitor the query I see multiple inner joins on "term_taxonomy_id"

```
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (25) 
      AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (25,268477,268482,268506,268507 etc etc) 
      AND AND tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (25,268477,268482,268506,268507 etc etc)
```

but when I run (in phpmyadmin) the same query without the inner joins on tt1.term_taxonomy_id and tt2.term_taxonomy_id I get the same results.

I tried to get rid of those inner joins by hooking a function into pre_get_posts

```
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) ) {
        $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( array (
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms' => 25,
            'include_children' => false
        ) ) );
    }
```

but it doesn't affect the query. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean other than by avoiding woocommerce?

Comment: Yes other than by avoiding woocommerce.

Comment: What I don't understand is why there are multiple inner joins on the same table (wp_term_relationships) cause I don't see why it's relevant? And how do I change the tax_query so it's not joining multiple times.